# get total price for the products in m2m field in save

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

Django 1.8 I'm trying to get total price for the products in m2m field.

```
from django.models.db import Sum

class Product(models.Model):
    ...
    price = models.DecimalField(default=0, max_digits=9, decimal_places=2)

class Order(models.Model):
    ...
    products = models.ManyToManyField(Product, related_name='orders')
    total = models.DecimalField()
    ...

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.total = self.products.all().annotate(Sum('price'))

        super(Order, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

When I try to save the Order object, the code above produce ValueError:

```
"<Order: None>" needs to have a value for field "order" before this
  many-to-many relationship can be used.
```

Comment: try to put your code **after** `super` class method call or use `post_save` signal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have specific requirements to save this total in your database? If not,

```
class Order(models.Model):
    ...
    products = models.ManyToManyField(Product, related_name='orders')
    ...

    @property
    def total(self):
        result = self.products.aggregate(Sum('price'))
        return result['price__sum']
```

Answer (score 0):

the best way to do it, it's by a signal:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/signals/#m2m-changed

here it's a example:

```
@receiver(m2m_changed, sender=BusquedaInmueble.zonas.through)
def post_save_busqueda_m2m (sender,  action, instance, *args, **kwargs):
  busqueda = instance
  if action == 'post_add':
```